# Can't get parameter value to insert into javascript string

Tags: javascript, string, parameters, parse-platform, twilio

I am using Parse.com with Twilio and I'm extremely close to fixing this problem. Right now I am using the following javascript code for my Parse.com cloud code (Account ID and Auth Token omitted):

```
// Include the Twilio Cloud Module and initialize it
var twilio = require("twilio");
twilio.initialize("MyAccountID","MyAuthToken");

// Create the Cloud Function
Parse.Cloud.define("inviteWithTwilio", function(request, response) {
// Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS
twilio.sendSMS({
From: "15978944848",
To: request.params.number,
Body: request.params.verificationCode,
}, {
success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
});
});
```

This works PERFECTLY. The purpose of this code is to send an SMS text message to my cell phone.

I get a text message to my phone and the "Body" value of "`request.params.verificationCode`" shows up in my text message as a 4 digit code like 5592.

Here is the problem though. I need to change the actual message so that when you look at it on your phone it reads "Here is your 4 digit code: 5592" but I cannot get that to work.

I can either use a sentence in parentheses by itself eg. "Here is your 4 digit code", or just use "`request.params.verificationCode`" by itself but I cannot get the 2 to work together.

I have been trying for over an hour now to get this to work. Have searched on google and SO for "how to insert variable into string" and I have followed the steps like inserting `request.params.verificationCode` into a variable and then trying to place a variable inside the body sentence(string) but I get errors every time I save and try to send the text message.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated and I apologize if any of my terminology is off but I'm only experienced with objective-c and this is my first time ever dealing with javascript.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What's the exact error you're seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to combine your custom text with the verification code using the string concatenation operator (`+`):

```
twilio.sendSMS({
    From: "xxxxxxxxx",
    To: request.params.number,
    Body: 'Here is your 4 digit code: ' + request.params.verificationCode,
}, ...
```

If `request.params.verificationCode` is a `Number` then it will be implicitly converted to a string before it is concatenated, otherwise it will just be concatenated.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly I'll accept the answer in 7min!

Comment: When I try doing this, and lets say verificationCode ends up being 5555, the text message shows up and there is no space in-between 5555 and the word "into"  : 'Please enter ' + request.params.verificationCode + 'into appname to finish creating your account.' I tried adding a space between ' and "into" but that causes an error. Any idea how to add the proper spacing?

Comment: @user3117509: It shouldn't cause an error. `'Please enter ' + request.params.verificationCode + ' into appname to finish creating your account.'` is perfectly valid. Just make sure you're not mixing single and double quotations improperly.

Comment: You are correct. I just copy/pasted your code and it worked fine. When I edit this javascript file and type text in the text editor for some reason instead of doing ' like you showed me it wants to do something very similar but the apostrophe has a curl to it. I'm guessing this is because of my settings in my TextEdit program on my macbook?

Comment: @user3117509: That's exactly it. They must be straight quotes, not the curly ones. Use a text editor that's set up for code and doesn't automatically replace straight quotes with curly ones (it may be a setting in your editor).

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help me with this beginner's issue and noob questions this is why stackoverflow kicks ass thank you.

Comment: @user3117509: My pleasure, that's why I'm part of this community!